# How do I implement a data oriented design in Rust?

Tags: rust, data-oriented-design

## Background

In game engine development we usually use a data oriented design for optimal memory and computation performance.

Let's take particle system as an example.

In a particle system, we have a lot of particles, and each particle may have several attributes such as positions, velocities, etc.

A typical implementation in C++ would be like this:

```
struct Particle {
    float positionX, positionY, positionZ;
    float velocityX, velocityY, velocityZ;
    float mass;
    // ...
};

struct ParticleSystem {
    vector<Particle> particles;
    // ...
};
```

One problem of this implementation is that the particle attributes are interleaved with each other.
This memory layout is not cache friendly and may not suitable for SIMD computations.

Instead in a data oriented design, we write following code:

```
struct ParticleAttribute {
    size_t size;
    size_t alignment;
    const char* semantic;
};

struct ParticleSystem {
    ParticleSystem(
        size_t numParticles,
        const ParticleAttribute* attributes,
        size_t bufferSize) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < numAttributes; ++i) {
            bufferSize += attributes[i].size * numParticles;
            // Also add paddings to satisfy the alignment requirements.
        }
        particleBuffer = malloc(bufferSize); 
    }

    uint8* getAttribute(const char* semantic) {
        // Locate the semantic in attributes array.
        // Compute the offset to the starting address of that attribute.
    }

    uint8* particleBuffer;      
};
```

Now we have only one allocation and each attribute resides in memory continuously.
To simulate the particles, we may write following code:

```
symplecticEuler(ps.getAttribute("positionX"), ps.getAttribute("velocityX"), dt);
```

The `getAttribute` function will get the starting address of a particular attribute.

## Question

I would like to know how to implement this in Rust.

My idea is to first create a class called `ParticleSystem`, which takes several `ParticleAttribute`s to calculate the total buffer size,
then allocate the memory for the buffer.
I think this can be done in Rust safe code.

The next step is to implement `getAttribute` function, which
will returns a reference to the starting address of a specific attribute.
I need your help here.
How do I get the raw address with an offset and cast it to a desired type(such as float*) and wrap that raw pointer to a mutable reference in Rust?

In addition, I think I should wrap that raw pointer to a mutable reference to array because I need to use SIMD lib to load four elements through that reference.
How do I achieve this using Rust?

---

Update: provide more information about the attributes.
The number and detailed information of attributes are determined in runtime.
The types of attributes can vary, but I think we only have to support the primitive ones(f32, f64, ints,...).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a very complicated way of implementing DOD, and the idea of using run-time lookup for getters makes me cringe.

The simple version is to simply have one memory allocation per attribute:

```
struct Particles {
    x: Vec<f32>,
    y: Vec<f32>,
}
```

which requires knowing the attributes beforehand.

Then there is no shenanigan for getting all the ys, they are just sitting there, already typed, waiting for you.

---

Extending this to dynamically determined attributes is not that complicated:

- we can use a `HashMap<String, xxx>` to look-up a given attribute at run-time
- we can use an `enum` to have a single `Value` to be stored in the hash-map which can take a variety of forms (the other solution would be using a trait)

This becomes:

```
#[derive(Debug, Hash, PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Value {
    UniformInt(i64),
    UniformFloat32(f32),
    UniformFloat64(f64),
    DistinctInt(Vec<i64>),
    DistinctFloat32(Vec<f32>),
    DistinctFloat64(Vec<f64>),
}

struct Particles {
    store: HashMap<String, Value>,
}
```

We could alternatively use 6 hash-maps... but unless one knows a priori what the type is (when the only thing one has is a string), then one has to look through all hashmaps one at a time: annoying, and time wasting.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I arrive this complicated way of implementing DOD because the flexibility on attributes is required. Usually the detailed attribute information(i.e. the number of attributes, and the exact semantics) comes from artists. In other word, this information are dynamic which cannot be determined before runtime.

Comment: @TheBusyTypist: I see... please edit the question with the relevant details then. It would also be worth knowing whether you only need to support `f32` (in which case a `HashMap<String, Vec<32>>` would work quite well) or if you need to support multiple types.

Comment: I have to support other primitive types such as `f64` or `int`s(for particle ID). As you suggested, now I think grouping attributes in separate `HashMap` by their types may be a valid solution.

Comment: The `HashMap` solution satisfies almost all requirements, but it still lacks some control at a finer level. One such example is to distinguish uniform and variable attributes. By uniform attribute I mean the attribute value is a constant among all particles, while it can be different for a variable attribute. We can store just a single value for the uniform attribute. In our `HashMap` solution we need to add another key to distinguish them. I am afraid combination explosion would occur in more complex situations.

Comment: I think `enum`s could save the day here: `enum Value { UniformInt(u64), UniformFloat32(f32), UniformFloat64(f64), VariableInt(Vec<u64>), VariableFloat32(Vec<f32>), VariableFloat64(Vec<f64>) }` and then `HashMap<String, Value>`.